# MVC Check if Model in View Has Records

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am struggling to determine if a Model passed to a View actually has any records.

The code below loops through the parent recordset and passes a parent parameter to a child recordset. I've tried `if (Model.Content != null)` but that doesn't seems to work, the code just thinks there are records, when actually there aren't.

Can somebody please review the code below and let me know what I am doing wrong?

```
<ul class="nav sf-menu clearfix">
    @foreach (var navigation in Model.Navigation)
    {
        if (Model.Content != null)
        {
            @Html.SubMenuLink(navigation.Title, navigation.Action, navigation.Controller)
            @Html.Raw("<ul>")
            foreach (var content in Model.Content.Where(c => c.NavigationId == navigation.Id))
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(content.Url))
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(content.Content1))
                    {
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        @Html.MenuLink(content.Title, "Home/Article/" + content.Id + "/" + ToFriendlyUrl(content.Title), "Home");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    @Html.MenuLink(content.Title, content.Url, "Home");
                }
            }
            @Html.Raw("</ul>")
            @Html.Raw("</li>")
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.MenuLink(navigation.Title, navigation.Action, navigation.Controller)
        }
    }
</ul>
```

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

**NavigationViewModel**

```
namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class NavigationViewModel
    {
        public List<Navigation> Navigation { get; set; }
        public List<Content> Content { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**HomeController**

```
public ActionResult Navigation()
{
    var navigationModel = new NavigationViewModel();
    navigationModel.Navigation = (from m in db.Navigations where (m.Main == true) orderby m.Position select m).ToList();
    navigationModel.Content = (from n in db.Contents where (n.Active == true) orderby n.Position select n).ToList();

    return View(navigationModel);
}
```

Comment: What is a type of `Model.Content`?

Comment: Why not adding required attribute on the your model properties and then for modelstate.isvalid check on postback?

Comment: I've added the Model and Controller code to aid a solution.

Answer (score 3):

It may have empty list items. Better check the `Count` property.

```
if (Model.Content != null && Model.Content.Count>0)
```

Assuming `Model.Content` may be the type of IList or Array

Comment: `Model.Content.Any()` would be a better option. But the asker has not given us any info on how the model is constructed or populated with values.

Answer (score 2):

If `Content` property is of **List** or **Array** type then do like this:

```
if(Model.Content != null && Model.Content.Count > 0)
{
    //do something
}
```

if its a **IEnumerable** of some type then:

```
if(Model.Content != null && Model.Content.Count() > 0)
{
   //do something
}
```

and if you are sure that `Model.Content` will not be passed `null` from action method, then you can use `Any()`:

```
if(Model.Content.Any())
{  
    //do something 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the Linq Method Any()

```
if (Model.Content.Any())
{

}
```

Edit: After second look. That if statement may not be right Model.Content inside the loop will always execute the same way. Are you use it isnt something like `navigation.Content.Any()`

Comment: I think I see the issue, the Model.Content is initially being passed all records so records do exists before I pass a Where clause `foreach (var content in Model.Content.Where(c => c.NavigationId == navigation.Id))` to find related Content records based on NavigationID. Not sure the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

```
Simply you can do something like this

In your C# class introduce new property named called Empty.

public class YourClass
{

    public bool Empty
    {
        get 
        { 
            return ( ColumnID== 0 )
        }
    }
}

Then in your Razor view you can use this Empty property for check weather model has values or not

@if (Model.Empty)
{
   @*what ever you want*@
}
else
{
   @*what ever you want*@
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that the Model.Content was initially being passed all records to the view so records did actually exist before the Where clause `foreach (var content in Model.Content.Where(c => c.NavigationId == navigation.Id))` to find related Content records based on NavigationID.

I have amended my code as follows:

```
<ul class="nav sf-menu clearfix">
    @foreach (var navigation in Model.Navigation)
    {
        int records = Model.Content.Count(c => c.NavigationId == navigation.Id);

        if (records > 0)
        {
            @Html.SubMenuLink(navigation.Title, navigation.Action, navigation.Controller)
            @Html.Raw("<ul>")
            foreach (var content in Model.Content.Where(c => c.NavigationId == navigation.Id))
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(content.Url))
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(content.Content1))
                    {
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        @Html.MenuLink(content.Title, "Home/Article/" + content.Id + "/" + ToFriendlyUrl(content.Title), "Home");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    @Html.MenuLink(content.Title, content.Url, "Home");
                }
            }
            @Html.Raw("</ul>")
            @Html.Raw("</li>")
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.MenuLink(navigation.Title, navigation.Action, navigation.Controller)
        }
    }
</ul>
```

I'm not sure this is the most elegant or efficient way to achieve the end goal, any suggestions to make the code more efficient I am happy to listen.

Answer (score 0):

```
@if (!Model.Any())
{
    Response.Redirect("Create");
}
```

Comment: Please enhance your answer and explain how this code block solves the problem.

Comment: Your post went into the [Low Quality Posts Review Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/17983181) because somebody flagged it as either "Not An Answer" or "Very Low Quality". This is (in my opinion) an incorrect flag - see [How do I properly use the “Not an Answer” flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185073/284827), which says: "When should I not use this flag?: The answer makes an attempt to answer the question, even if it is wrong or inaccurate or you disagree with it". Your post should have been downvoted, not flagged.

Answer (score 0):

If model empty then return empty default content will give you what do you expected

```
if (!model.Any())
   return Content("");
```